# How can I purchase a "Standing / Non-reserved Seat" Korail train ticket online?

Tags: trains, tickets, online-resources, south-korea, fare-class

"Standing / Non-reserved Seat" is the cheapest fare on [Korail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korail):

[image]

But how can I purchase a "Standing / Non-reserved Seat" Korail train ticket online?

I only see two purchase options (first class and economy) on [Lets Korial](https://www.letskorail.com/ebizbf/EbizBfTicketSearch.do):

[image]

while clicking on fare:

[image]

shows a third fare category "Standing / Non-reserved Seat" (shown in the first screenshot).

E.g. the SNCF in France does [allow](https://groups.google.com/g/fr.misc.transport.rail/c/vtfjrOME-XI?pli=1) online booking for non-reserved seats ("[TGV : place(s) assise(s) non garantie(s)](https://www.google.com/search?q=TGV+%3A+place(s)+assise(s)+non+garantie(s))"), so it's conceivable that Korail allows the same.

Comment: I checked the Korean language settings of the Korail app, which offers different options from the English language settings (you can't choose your site if the app is set to English!), and there seems to be no way to reserve a standing seat. The accepted answer to this question (https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/80349/do-tickets-for-these-korean-trains-have-to-be-booked-in-advance) from a Korean citizen seems to confirm it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, you can't. Online booking is always for reserving seats, it doesn't make sense to book a non-reserved seat. To get the non-reserved seat, you have to buy the ticket yourself at the station physically, which is a *basic fare ticket*.

*Similar to what @lambshaanxy has mentioned*

*Note that you can book non-reserved seats e.g. in SNCF France [here](https://groups.google.com/g/fr.misc.transport.rail/c/vtfjrOME-XI?pli=1) - @Franck Dernoncourt*