# Using Korail trains in South Korea without advance booking?

Tags: trains, tickets, south-korea, no-advance-plans

I plan to take a [Korail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korail) train in October in South Korea. I don't know exactly at what time I'll reach the train station. Is it practical to just show up at Korail train stations and buy a ticket there? Or do trains often get fully booked?

If that matters, the trip is from  [Seoul Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seoul_Station)
 to [Singyeongju station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singyeongju_station).

This question is inspired from [Using trains and buses in India without advance booking?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5284/1810) and is a follow-up of [How can I purchase a "Standing / Non-reserved Seat" Korail train ticket online?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/175921/1810)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on personal experience, it is practical to just show up at Seoul Station *during the week* and buy a ticket for a KTX train on the spot. If all of the seats have been reserved, there are standing tickets available, too.

Based on your [earlier question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/175921/how-can-i-purchase-a-standing-non-reserved-seat-korail-train-ticket-online) where you would prefer the option of a non-reserved/standing ticket to save 7400 KRW (US$/€5.50 or so), perhaps the prospect of potentially standing for a couple of hours does not concern you.

However, for the benefit of others, my wife and I once endured a standing journey from Seoul to Busan — purchased at the station on a whim for a midweek jaunt during the summer — and the experience encouraged us to always book tickets in advance for future train travel in South Korea. Busan is a very popular summertime destination, though. Your odds of a seat likely would be better on a random weekday in October.

Trains often do get fully booked on the weekends and on holidays and there is a limit to the number of standing tickets offered, as well. For example, Korail reported that [48.3% of tickets were reserved](https://world.kbs.co.kr/service/news_view.htm?lang=e&Seq_Code=171791) for Chuseok (Mid-Autumn Festival) this year on the *first day* they went on sale (30 days in advance).

If you want to travel on the weekend, a holiday, or there is a special event/festival, etc, it would be wise to book a ticket in advance.